# Join Events Between Time Intervals and Get the Optimal Time Difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The scenario is this: Within this time grid, join on documentation that has a time difference in minutes less than or equal to what is allowed in the time block. Display the time the event occurred and the related documented EventValue.

The solution I have now takes the first time stamp in each check interval, however that falls apart when there is documentation very early in the check interval and also very late in the same check interval. For an example see the TimeDiff column and then check the data in the Events table.

How can I join on one row in each time block that is the "optimal" time difference for the allowed time in each check interval?

DBMS is SSMS 2016

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeGrid
    ([PersonID] int, [TimeBlockCD] varchar(6), [TimeBlockNBR] int, [CheckInterval] datetime, [NextCheckInterval] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO TimeGrid
    ([PersonID], [TimeBlockCD], [TimeBlockNBR], [CheckInterval], [NextCheckInterval])
VALUES
    (123456, '5 min', 5, '2019-11-12 08:50:00', '2019-11-12 08:55:00'),
    (123456, '5 min', 5, '2019-11-12 08:55:00', '2019-11-12 09:00:00'),
    (123456, '5 min', 5, '2019-11-12 09:00:00', '2019-11-12 09:05:00'),
    (123456, '15 min', 15, '2019-11-12 09:05:00', '2019-11-12 09:20:00'),
    (123456, '15 min', 15, '2019-11-12 09:20:00', '2019-11-12 09:35:00'),
    (123456, '30 min', 30, '2019-11-12 09:35:00', '2019-11-12 10:05:00')
;


CREATE TABLE Events
    ([PersonID] int, [EventDTS] datetime, [EventDSC] varchar(6), [EventTypeID] int, [EventValue] int)
;

INSERT INTO Events
    ([PersonID], [EventDTS], [EventDSC], [EventTypeID], [EventValue])
VALUES
    (123456, '2019-11-12 09:05:00', 'Event3', 3, 316),
    (123456, '2019-11-12 08:56:00', 'Event3', 3, 747),
    (123456, '2019-11-12 08:59:00', 'Event3', 3, 343),
    (123456, '2019-11-12 09:03:00', 'Event3', 3, 228)
;
```

My Attempt:

```
SELECT
 tg.PersonID
,tg.TimeBlockCD
,tg.TimeBlockNBR
,tg.CheckInterval
,tg.NextCheckInterval
,e.EventDTS
,e.EventValue
,DATEDIFF(minute,LAG(e.EventDTS,1,tg.CheckInterval) over (PARTITION BY tg.PersonID ORDER BY e.EventDTS),e.EventDTS) as EventTimeDiff
FROM TimeGrid tg
OUTER APPLY (SELECT
              e.PersonID
             ,e.EventDTS
             ,e.EventDSC
             ,e.EventTypeID
             ,e.EventValue
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.PersonID ORDER BY e.EventDTS) as RowNBR
             FROM Events e
             WHERE 1=1
             and e.PersonID = tg.PersonID
             and e.EventTypeID = 3
             and e.EventDTS between tg.CheckInterval and tg.NextCheckInterval
             ) e

WHERE 1=1
and (e.RowNBR is null or e.RowNBR = 1)

ORDER BY tg.CheckInterval
```